# Does Linux support "like '%c'" filter(cql_filter)

Tags: query, cql-filter, getfeature

I can execute the following request:

http://My.host:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&version=1.1.0&typeName=topp:states&cql_filter=STATE_NAME like 'California'

But I can't execute the following one:

http://My.host:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&version=1.1.0&typeName=topp:states&cql_filter=STATE_NAME like 'C%'

Here goes the error message:
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: .http://My.host:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=topp:states&cql_filter=STATE_NAME%20like%20%27C%%27
Line Number 1, Column 1:

I think something is wrong when I use % he encode the request and something happens...

GeoServer:V2.1.4
Browser:FireFox
SO: Ubunto

Comment: Solved
switch "%" to "%25"

Comment: please enter above comment as your own answer below.  It's ok to answer your own questions.

Comment: Geoist got in there before him ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '%' character should be encoded as '%25' inside a URL.